# RxSwift `observeWeakly` on certain UIView properties fails while `observe` does work

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, rx-swift

The question is pretty straight forward:

I have the following extension to subscribe to the `alpha` and `hidden` properties of an UIView using RxSwift. But this errors with an `invalidPropertyName` error.

Just simply replacing `observeWeakly` with `observe` fixes the error but I would rather not do this to prevent possible retention cycles.
The very same code does work for properties like the frame and bounds, and as far as I am aware, at least `hidden` is a KVO-compliant property.

Is this a known issue or is there any other way to observe these properties while targeting iOS 12.0?

The code in question:

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIView {
    
    
    var observeAlpha: Observable<CGFloat?> {
        get {
            return observeWeakly(CGFloat.self, "alpha")
                .do(
                    onError: {
                        print($0)
                    }
                )
                .catchErrorJustReturn(1.0)
                .startWith(base.alpha)
        }
    }

    
    var observeIsHidden: Observable<Bool?> {
        get {
            return observeWeakly(Bool.self, "hidden")
                .do(
                    onError: {
                        print($0)
                    }
                )
                .catchErrorJustReturn(false)
                .startWith(base.isHidden)
        }
    }
}
```

The two errors:

```
Object `<UIView: 0x7f9a4654a170; frame = (0 0; 375 812); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002464940>>` doesn't have a property named `alpha`.
```

```
Object `<UITransitionView: 0x7f9a4654a170; frame = (0 0; 375 812); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002464940>>` doesn't have a property named `hidden`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After encountering this issue again it actually got fixed by just not even trying to observe the UIView's properties. Instead I observe the underlaying CALayer for any changes, which after some basic testing seems to do the trick.

```swift
extension Reactive where Base: UIView {
    var observeAlpha: Observable<Float?> {
        get {
            return base.layer.rx.observeWeakly(Float.self, "opacity")
                .catchAndReturn(1.0)
                .startWith(base.layer.opacity)
        }
    }
    
    
    var observeIsHidden: Observable<Bool?> {
        get {
            return base.layer.rx.observeWeakly(Bool.self, "hidden")
                .catchAndReturn(false)
                .startWith(base.layer.isHidden)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I looks like the `observe` operator stores the keypath directly while the `observeWeakly` tries to parse it out. There looks to be a bug on the latter code to me.

The solution is to not use your view as if it was a model. The only way the `alpha` value changes is if you set it. Instead of observing the view's alpha or hidden properties, you should be observing whatever it is that is causing those properties to change.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not going to be my code that is going to edit the `isHidden` and `alpha` properties. It is part of an user analytics bundle that is supposed to automatically track the viewability of certain views passed to the SDK, such as asserting the alpha is larger than 0.0 and isHidden == false. In the case of `UITableViewCells` they are set to `isHidden = true` by the UITableView in between reuses, which is a lot harder to intercept without building in edge case handling for all of these UIView subclasses. Just going to file a bug report on GH for now
Thank you for your help though!

Comment: And obviously fork it to see if your theory does in deed fix the keypath issue.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question, as it simply ignores the fact that one might need to expose some custom property computed in the view itself, eg. specific touch event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `methodInvoked` to observe the invoke of the setter on those properties.

```
extension RxSwift.Reactive where Base: UIView {

    var didChangeHidden: Observable<Bool> {
        return methodInvoked(#selector(setter: base.isHidden))
            .map { $0.first as? Bool ?? false }
    }

    var didChangeAlpha: Observable<CGFloat> {
        return methodInvoked(#selector(setter: base.alpha))
            .map { $0.first as? CGFloat ?? 1 }
    }

}
```

Better would be to use store property instead of computed property if those observables are going to be subscribed several times.

```
extension RxSwift.Reactive where Base: UIView {

    var didChangeHidden: Observable<Bool> {
        let observable: Observable<Bool>
        if let existing = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &didSetHiddenAssociatedKey) as? Observable<Bool> {
            observable = existing
        } else {
            observable = methodInvoked(#selector(setter: base.isHidden))
                .map { $0.first as? Bool ?? false }
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &didSetHiddenAssociatedKey, observable, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
        return observable
    }

    var didChangeAlpha: Observable<CGFloat> {
        let observable: Observable<CGFloat>
        if let existing = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &didSetAlphaAssociatedKey) as? Observable<CGFloat> {
            observable = existing
        } else {
            observable = methodInvoked(#selector(setter: base.alpha))
                .map { $0.first as? CGFloat ?? 1 }
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &didSetAlphaAssociatedKey, observable, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
        return observable
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just encountered a similar issue again, it boils down to those properties most likely just not being KVO compliant. I ended up solving it by observing the underlying CALayer's properties.